# Skip before action not skipping in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, before-filter

I have used skip before action so that the application should allow the four pages(client_details,client_process,login,validate_login). But the action does not works as I expected. It is not allowing the user to login. I dont know why. Kindly please help.

My Users controller,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :check_session, :only=>[:client_details,:client_process,:login,:validate_login]
  require 'securerandom'
  def client_details
    @client=Client.new
  end

  def client_process
    params.permit!
    @client=Client.new(client_params)
    if @client.save
      Notify.scop(@client).deliver
      flash[:notice] = " your infomation is registered,wait for approval"
      redirect_to :action=> "login"
    else 
      render "client_details" 
      flash[:notice] = "sorry..."
    end
  end

  def login
    @user=User.new
    render :layout=>false
 end

 def validate_login
   params.permit!
   @user=User.where params[:user]
   $userid=@user.pluck(:id)[0]
   if not @user.blank?
     @chk=User.where(:username=>params[:user][:username]).pluck(:role)[0]
     @chk1=User.where(:username=>params[:user][:username]).pluck(:block_status)[0]
     if @chk=="Admin" 
       if @chk1==nil
         session[:user_id]=@user.first.id
         redirect_to :action=>"admin_page"
       else
         flash[:notice] = "sorry!... Administrator blocked you..."
         redirect_to root_path
       end
     elsif @chk=="user"
       redirect_to root_path
     elsif @chk==nil
       redirect_to :action=>"client_page"
     end
   else
     flash[:notice] = "Enter valid username and password" 
     redirect_to root_path
   end  
 end
end
```

My Application controller,

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_action :check_session
  def check_session
    if session[:user_id].blank?
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Is `check_session` definitely being called, or could this be a side-effect of something else? Try using a `raise` or `puts` at the start of `check_session` if you're not sure.

Comment: check_session is called. Look at my server log.                            Started GET "/users/client_page" for 192.168.1.102 at 2016-06-10 16:48:46 +0530
Cannot render console from 192.168.1.102! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by UsersController#client_page as HTML
Redirected to http://192.168.1.59:3000/
**Filter chain halted as :check_session rendered or redirected**
Completed 302 Found in 2ms

Comment: Ahah, your skip_before_action doesn't include #client_page

Comment: Sorry. I cant get you. What do mean?

Comment: The action getting called in your controller is #client_page. Your `skip_before_filter` doesn't include that action, so it's still getting called.

Comment: are you getting any error or redirecting to root ???

Comment: @Mukesh. Its redirecting to root

Comment: @tombeynon. I dont want the client_page in skip_before_action.

Comment: I think. =>   before_action :check_session ... is calling first,

Comment: check once it by putting logger

Answer (score 0):

The log entry you gave was..

Processing by UsersController#client_page as HTML Redirected to 192.168.1.59:3000 Filter chain halted as :check_session rendered or redirected Completed 302 Found in 2ms

The action being called in your UsersController is `#client_page`.

Your `skip_before_filter` doesn't include `#client_page`

```
skip_before_action :check_session, :only=>[:client_details,:client_process,:login,:validate_login]
```

Therefore, `#check_session` will always be called for the `#client_page` action.